# Function from dependency and Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a problem with AngularJS Service and Jasmine test. I use service dependency in another service, and when I try to make Unit Test I get an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating sso.getSession().userId')

I have one service sso with function to get Session. In session I have saved for example userId and email.

```
myApp.service('sso', function($rootScope) {
    var session;

    function initSession(){
       ....
       someData = .....;

       session = someData;
    }

    function getSession() {
        return session;
    }
})
```

And another service where I use sso services function (and also userContext - with userContext I don't have any problem)

```
myApp.service('adminLogStore', function($http, userContext, sso) {
    var self = this;

    this.saveLog = function(log, userContext.userId) {
        return .........
    }

    var admin = {
        id: sso.getSession().userId,
        email: sso.getSession().userEmail,
        login: sso.getSession().username
    };

    .......
}
```

And finally - my unit test:

```
describe('Service count ', function () {
    var $t, $httpBackend, adminLogStore;
    var uid = 5;

    beforeEach(ModuleBuilder.forModules('myapp.common', 'testing.helpers')
        .serviceWithMocksExcept('adminLogStore', '$rootScope', '$http', '$q', '$location')
        .build()
    );

    beforeEach(inject(function (TestingService, _$httpBackend_, _adminLogStore_, userContext, sso) {
        $t = TestingService;
        adminLogStore = _adminLogStore_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        userContext.userId = uid;
    }));

    it('good value', inject(function () {
        expect(userContext.userId).toBe(5);
    }));
});
```

How I should mock sso function? I doesn't get any error if I don use .userId after sso.getSession() .

I try to add mock inside beforeEach, just under userContext.userId, but it doesn't work:

```
var user = {
    userId: 5,
    userEmail: 'test@o2.pl',
    username: 'test'
};
sso = jasmine.createSpyObj('sso', ['getSession']);
sso.getSession = function() {
     return user;
};
```

---

### --- EDIT

Now I try to mock admin object instead to mock sso object but without any results.

```
var user = {
    id: 5,
    email: 'test@o2.pl',
    login: 'test'
};

beforeEach(inject(function (TestingService, _$httpBackend_, _adminLogStore_, userContext) {
    $t = TestingService;
    adminLogStore = _adminLogStore_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    userContext.userId = uid;
    adminLogStore.admin = user;
}
```

and I change in my adminLogStore service:

```
this.admin = {
    // id: 12,
    id: sso.getSession().userId,
    email: sso.getSession().userEmail,
    login: sso.getSession().username
};
```

but still I get the same error.

---

### --- Edit 2

I try also mock sso.getSession() like this, but it doesn't work:

```
spyOn(sso, "getSession").and.returnValue(user);
```

Comment: When do you set this session variable?

Comment: This variable is created during bootstrap by another function initSession() (is called in bootstrap). On production I have access to sso.getSession() and I have many additional information (not only userId and email). I want mock this data for Unit test. 
I add in my question information about initSession()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally - it's my solutions. Create mock, and add return user as getSession function:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (TestingService, _$httpBackend_, _adminLogStore_, userContext, _ssoMock_) {
    $t = TestingService;
    adminLogStore = _adminLogStore_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    userContext.userId = uid;
    ssoMock = _ssoMock_;
    ssoMock.getSession.and.returnValue(user);
}
```

Of course it's necessary to declare var ssoMock.